# drag&drop dom elements inside contenteditable div

Tags: jquery, html, contenteditable, drag

I have the following html structure:

```
<div contenteditable="true">
     this is a <span class='gat'>draggable</span> text and i would like to <span class='gat'>drag it inside</span> the div parent.  
</div>
```

I want the span elements to be draggable only inside their parent div dom. if i want to move the second span a the begining, i would get :

```
<div contenteditable="true">
     <span class='gat'>drag it inside</span> this is a <span class='gat'>draggable</span> text and i would like to the div parent.  
</div>
```

I searching for a solution compatible with all major browser. (i'm using JQuery).

**EDIT** : Here is an exemple of what i need (without the need to click before to drag) : http://jsfiddle.net/s82Ex/

Comment: you can do it with jquery ui library, https://jqueryui.com/draggable/

Comment: Yes but i don't want the span to go anywhere, it should be inserted between text, not over and whitout white space

Answer (score 1):

Use jquery UI for this here is the code to implement this:

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script>
</script>
<style>
.parent{
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    width: 1000px;
    height: 1000px;
    border: 2px solid;
}


</style>


<div class="parent" contenteditable="true">
     this is a <span class='gat'>draggable</span> text and i would like to <span class='gat'>drag it inside</span> the div parent.  
</div>
<script>
$('.gat').draggable({ containment: "parent" });
</script>
```

for more reference check this [link](https://jqueryui.com/draggable/)

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/ishandemon/junq47q9/

**DEMO2:** http://jsfiddle.net/ishandemon/junq47q9/2/

Comment: thanks for your answer, but on the fiddle, the text is draggable, but leaving white space and on the drop, it goes over the other words. Any ideas how to keep the formating (the same way as if you dbclick on a word in the fiddle, and move the word at another place) ?

Comment: it doesn't match exactly what i need because i can't drag the 'draggable span' between any text wrapped into span. here is an exemple of what i need (whitout the need to click before to drag) http://jsfiddle.net/s82Ex/

Comment: @user2733521 seems like it's not working on chrome :(

Comment: it's not the solution because of compatibility problem, but the result i need to reach :D

Answer (score 0):

You can use `range` to select the span on `mousedown`, then it'll behave like selected text that you can drag. Like this:

```
    var gatSpans = document.getElementsByClassName('gat');

    for (var i = 0; i < gatSpans.length; i++) {
        gatSpans[i].onmousedown = function (e) {

            var sel = window.getSelection();
            var range = document.createRange();
            range.setStart(e.target, 0);
            range.setEnd(e.target, 1);
            sel.removeAllRanges();
            sel.addRange(range);
        }
    }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/6Lobg46a/3/

EDIT:

To make it work more than one time with this approach, it's easier to use delegated events, and you'll have to set the dataTransfer to keep the span on drag. Like this:

```
    $('div').on('mousedown', '.gat', function (e) {

        var sel = window.getSelection();
        var range = document.createRange();
        range.selectNode(e.target);
        sel.removeAllRanges();
        sel.addRange(range);

    });
    $('div')[0].ondragstart = function(e){

        e.dataTransfer.setData('text/html', '<span class="gat">'+e.dataTransfer.getData("text/plain")+'</span>')
    }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/6Lobg46a/6/